# For all levels of a factor, return all levels of another factor from same dataframe - using dplyr ? r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a very large dataset containing historical soccer results.  Here is a portion of it:

```
  Season              home          visitor  FT
    1954       Aston Villa              SHW 0-0
    1956       Aston Villa              SHW 5-0
    1957       Aston Villa              SHW 2-0
    1960       Aston Villa              SHW 4-1
    1987       Aston Villa              HUL 5-0
    1987       Aston Villa              HUD 1-1
    1987       Aston Villa              BLB 1-1
    1933 Preston North End              NOT 4-0
    1958 Preston North End              NOT 3-5
    1960 Preston North End              NOT 0-1
    1962 Preston North End              SWA 6-3
    1976           Walsall              SHW 5-1
    1977           Walsall              SHW 1-1
    2002           Walsall Sheffield United 0-1
    2002           Walsall       Gillingham 1-0
```

For each home team (factor), I wish to return the unique levels of another factor (Season) that occur for that factor.  In the above example, this would return:

```
Aston Villa - 1954, 1956, 1957, 1960, 1987
Preston North End - 1933, 1958, 1960, 1962
Walsall - 1976, 1977, 2002
```

I thought about trying to do this in dplyr as an exercise.  However, I'm not getting this right.

I tried this:

```
library(dplyr)
demodf%>%
group_by(home)%>%
summarize(levels(Season))
#Error: expecting a single value
```

Just out of interest, I did the following to see if I could see the first year returned for each factor/home team:

```
demodf%>%
group_by(home)%>%
summarize(levels(Season)[1])
```

this gave me this:

```
#               home levels(Season)[1]
#1       Aston Villa              1933
#2 Preston North End              1933
#3           Walsall              1933
```

which is not right - it has just returned the first level of the Season factor in the whole dataframe (1933), rather than the first year/level of the Season factor for each team respectively - I thought the `group.by` would have helped get at this.

I appreciate any help with this.

The below should enable you to reproduce the above table:

```
demodf<-structure(list(Season = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("1933", "1954", 
"1956", "1957", "1958", "1960", "1962", "1976", "1977", "1987", 
"2002"), class = "factor"), home = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Aston Villa", 
"Preston North End", "Walsall"), class = "factor"), visitor = structure(c(7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 2L), .Label = c("BLB", 
"Gillingham", "HUD", "HUL", "NOT", "Sheffield United", "SHW", 
"SWA"), class = "factor"), FT = structure(c(1L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 
4L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 11L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("0-0", 
"0-1", "1-0", "1-1", "2-0", "3-5", "4-0", "4-1", "5-0", "5-1", 
"6-3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Season", "home", "visitor", 
"FT"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Are you interested in non-dplyr solutions?

Comment: I'd be interested in any solution - the neater, the better.  I thought it might be good to do in dplyr, but perhaps not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you can just use `by`:

```
with(demodf, by(Season, home, unique))
# home: Aston Villa
# [1] 1954 1956 1957 1960 1987
# Levels: 1933 1954 1956 1957 1958 1960 1962 1976 1977 1987 2002
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# home: Preston North End
# [1] 1933 1958 1960 1962
# Levels: 1933 1954 1956 1957 1958 1960 1962 1976 1977 1987 2002
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# home: Walsall
# [1] 1976 1977 2002
# Levels: 1933 1954 1956 1957 1958 1960 1962 1976 1977 1987 2002
```

---

The "data.table" package can also handle `list`s as columns in a `data.table`, like this:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(demodf)
DT[, list(Season = list(unique(Season))), by = home]
#                 home                   Season
# 1:       Aston Villa 1954,1956,1957,1960,1987
# 2: Preston North End      1933,1958,1960,1962
# 3:           Walsall           1976,1977,2002
```

Note the structure of the result:

```
str(.Last.value)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ home  : Factor w/ 3 levels "Aston Villa",..: 1 2 3
#  $ Season:List of 3
#   ..$ : Factor w/ 11 levels "1933","1954",..: 2 3 4 6 10
#   ..$ : Factor w/ 11 levels "1933","1954",..: 1 5 6 7
#   ..$ : Factor w/ 11 levels "1933","1954",..: 8 9 11
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: `data.frames` support lists too: `aggregate(Season ~ home, data=demodf,FUN=function(x) as.character(unique(x)) )`, though `aggregate` doesn't play nicely with factors.

Comment: @thelatemail, I am aware that `data.frame`s support lists too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Having `Season` as a factor complicates matters slightly, however

```
demodf %>% group_by(home) %>% do(data.frame(Seasons = unique(.$Season)))
```

will work.

Note it is simpler to use `unique` instead of `levels`

Comment: If that's the output, why not just something like `unique(demodf[c("Season", "home")])`? (Your solution just gives me a long table as a result.)

Comment: @AnandaMahto very true.This does show the use of `do`. I think the `data.table` [,list(list(...),...]` solution is the best by far!

Comment: @mnel. May be `as.data.frame(demodf %>% group_by(home)%>% do(Seasons=as.character(unique(.$Season))))`

Answer (score 0):

I used paste to mimic the output you wanted:

```
demodf%>%
  group_by(home)%>%
  summarise( summary =  paste(unique(Season),collapse=","))
```

which gives

```
               home                  summary
1       Aston Villa 1954,1956,1957,1960,1987
2 Preston North End      1933,1958,1960,1962
3           Walsall           1976,1977,2002
```